# Как в строке после 100 символа найти пробел и обрезать после него строку?

Tags: javascript, строки

Есть строка и необходимо после 100 символа найти пробел и обрезать строку.
Буду признателен за помощь.

Comment: Читать https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String обязательно.

Comment: `indexOf` + `subString`. Ссылка на справку есть. `length` ещё понадобится.

Comment: Спасибо! Суть понял.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция **[String.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)** имеет ещё второй параметр, в котором можно указать начало поиска.

```
 var res = description.slice(0, description.indexOf(' ', 100));
```

Comment: Спасибо! Не знал про второй аргумент.

Answer (score 1):

```
 cutDescription(description) {
    if (description.length > 200) {
      let res = description.slice(0, 200);
      return description.slice(0, res.lastIndexOf(' '));
    }
    return description;
 }
```

Решил таким образом